# Create IT-system for a private company in NemLog-in

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2, nemlogin

Is it only possible to create public IT-systems in NemLog-in or not? I'm using the [ITfoxtec Identity Saml 2.0](https://www.itfoxtec.com/IdentitySaml2) component. It looks like the [ITfoxtec SAML 2.0 sample](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/tree/master/test/TestWebAppCoreNemLogin3Sp) is configured with an IT-system for a private company.

Answer (score 4):

The 'old' NemLog-in 2 supporting NemID only support public IT-systems. Where the new NemLog-in 3 supporting MitID (and NemID) both support public IT-systems an IT-systems for private companies.

**Updated**

The [ITfoxtec SAML 2.0 sample](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/tree/master/test/TestWebAppCoreNemLogin3Sp) is configured with a private IT-system in NemLog-in 3.

Comment: Dont this imply that you have a public it-system created with nemlogin 3? and to my knowledge MitID-Ervherv is not accessible yet. Does this imply that you created a it-system in the new management portal for private (with a broker) and testing against that (knowing it is the same that will be made accessible for MitID-Erhverv :)

Comment: Yes I have a private IT-system configured in the new management portal for NemLog-in 3. Both public and private IT-systems can use both personal and professionel MitID identities, it is furthermore configurable. Professionel MitID is MitID-Ervherv, which as you say will be accessable later.